# How to reload dropdown list values in asp.net mvc3 without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing a MVC3 application which interacts with a db. I'm using a form to create an entity and one of the attributes is dependent on another table. To ensure referential integrity, I am populating a drop down list to restrict the user as follows:

```
var processGroups = repository.getAllProcessGroups();
ViewBag.processGroup_drpdwn = new SelectList(processGroups, "process_group_id", "process_group_name");
return View(); //this is my Creation view
```

Then, in my View I display the dropdown as

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("groups", (SelectList)ViewBag.processGroup_drpdwn, new { id = "groupsList" })
         @Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddGroup", null, new { @class = "addGroupLink" })

    </div>
```

To make things easier on the user, I have implemented a [modal dialog](http://ricardocovo.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/asp-mvc3-editing-records-with-jqueryui-dialogs-and-ajaxforms/) using jQuery which allows the user to add an option to the db without having to leave the form to enter it on another page. This all works fine, my Controller returns the partial view, validates the stuff and posts it to the db. Unfortunately, the user has to refresh the page for the new option to get loaded from the db into the drop down list.

I'm trying to update the dropdown list using JSON and JQuery after the insert, but for some reason it is not working.

**Additional Info:**

Here is the relevant section of the modal form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddGroup", "Process", null,
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "update-message",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
    }, new { @id = "addGroupForm" }))
```

Here is a method which returns the groups as a JSON list:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ShowGroups()
    {
        var groups = repository.getAllProcessGroups();
        List<SelectListItem> list=new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (PROCESS_GROUP p in groups)
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = p.PROCESS_GROUP_ID.ToString(), Text = p.PROCESS_GROUP_NAME });
        }
        return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is the jQuery snippet of code which runs after my data has been inserted:

```
function loadGroups() {
    alert();
    $.getJSON("/Process/ShowGroups", null, function (data) {
        var selectList = $("#groupsList");
        selectList.empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
            var option = $('<option>').text(optionData.Text).val(optionData.Value);
            selectList.append(option);
        });
    });
}
function updateSuccess() {
    if ($("#update-message").html() == "True") {

        loadGroups();
        $('#updateDialog').dialog('close');
        //twitter type notification
        $('#commonMessage').html("Successfully Added");
        $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);

    }
    else {
        $("#update-message").show();
    }
    }
```

The `loadGroups()` begins but nothing happens. I also don't get any error messages explaining what went wrong.

**UPDATE:**

Works now. I had to remove `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` from the Action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#mydropdown").change(function () {
    // let's assume /list page prints a JSON string
    $.getJSON('/list', function (data) {
       var result = '';
       for (var i = 0, iL = data.length; i < iL; i++) {
           result += '<option value="' + data[i].value + '">' + data[i].text + '</option>';
       }
       $("#otherdropdown").html( result );
    });
});
```

This is only one option... use your logic and adapt it to your system. C ya!

Comment: +1: This should be the accepted answer; and yet somebody down-voted it.

Comment: Yeah, this deserves an upvote just on the basis of "C ya," not to mention that it's right.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an action that returns the updated list (as html, or json ). In the updateSuccess function call that action with jQuery's ajax function.

Comment: I tried to implement this and I updated the question. i think I'm close but it still isn't quite working

Comment: Works now. I had to remove [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] from the Action to get it to return the JSON list.

Answer (score 0):

Try using firebug to inspect what is being returned back via AJAX when you submit that AJAX form.

Then you need to add a variable to your `updateSuccess()` function to access the return data like this:

```
function updateSuccess(ajaxResult) {
     $("#update-message").html(ajaxResult.SomeValue); //example
}
```

Note that depending on how the data is formed coming back to you, the implementation within that function above will need to be changed.