# MVC3 - repopulate dropdownlist with Ajax after modal form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building an MVC3 application and would like to have a form with a dropdown list, and if the option the user requires is not there, then they can click on a link to open a modal popup box, fill a different form out, submit it and close the form, and repopulate the dropdown list which will contain the option they have just added.

I've looked at options of using either jQuery Ajax or MVC Ajax (e.g. Ajax.BeginForm, Ajax.ActionLink).  Can anyone recommend the best one to use, and also point me in the direction of a good tutorial?  Been having a good look today but can't find anything that really does what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reload dropdown list values in asp.net mvc3 without refreshing page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189207/how-to-reload-dropdown-list-values-in-asp-net-mvc3-without-refreshing-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use jQuery in these situations.  In this case I would use .ajax() post to perform the form's action.  I would then add a handler in the .ajax()'s success event to add my new item to the dropdown using append, example minus all properties except for success handler:

```
$.ajax({ 
  success: function() {$(myDropDown).append(theNewListItem);}
});
```

You can generate theNewListItem by having it created and returned from the server in the ajax call, or simly build it using the current form values, assuming the values have been validated.